# How to keep session values with symfony sessions?

Tags: php, symfony, session

With symfony, I have a login system. When logging, I set some variables into session with this code:

```php
$session = new Session();
$session->set("API_KEY", $myApiKey);
$session->set("username", $username);
```

This works for some times (around 1 hour). But, after not using the website, values change to be blank. Now, both are empty (even if when login, they wasn't).

I changed the PHP `session.gc-maxlifetime` ([Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime)) to an high variable (as 99999999, which is around 190 years). Now, when it's more than one night (like 2 days), the problem appear again. It means after multiple hours, session values are resetted to empty.

If people logout and relogin, values are back.

In my `security.yaml`, I have (604800 is in documentation and correspond to one week):

```yaml
remember_me:
   secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
   lifetime: 604800
```

How can I keep thoses values?

Comment: It may be related to a cleaning made by the system (cron, ... ) that clean the session files unregarding php conf ?

Comment: There is no specific cron, and which value to do want from php conf ?

Comment: Have a look at this : https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/session.html#session-idle-time-keep-alive then check the value of `$session->getMetadataBag()->getLifetime();`

Comment: @Sami The value of `$session->getMetadataBag()->getLifetime();` is 0

Comment: @Elikill58 The PHP doc (https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime) says the session will be destroyed when browser is closed ! Try to change the value of the parameter

Comment: @Sami oh yes, just tried to restart the browser and the bug appear. I changed `session.cookie_lifetime` to an high value, restarted apache but the problem is already here (nothing changed)

Comment: @Elikill58 Are you actually using the Symfony framework?  If so you would never actually create a session yourself.  Instead you would do something like `$request->getSession`.  Though to be honest I don't really understand how what you are doing is working at all.

Comment: @Cerad most of the time, I'm using `$request` as you showed, but only one time, I set variable with new session (only when login - to set username). But the method used doesn't change my actual issue

Comment: Well okay. Have you tried adjusting framework session cookie_lifetime in framework.yaml?

Comment: @Cerad thanks you, I set it to 3600 seconds and now it's fine, I restarted browser and values are already here

Comment: Glad to help.  Still don't understand why you are using `new Session()`.  Just seems unnecessary.  If your code does not have access to the current request then use RequestStack::getSession(). But hey, if it works then it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to come from cookie session that was resetting fast. Lifetime were at 0 by default, and I didn't changed them. At 0, the value is removed when the browser is closed, so each time I close it, it's removed.

To fix it, I :

1. Changed [`session.cookie_lifetime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-lifetime) value in the `php.ini` file
2. Added in `framework.yaml`:

```yaml
framework:
    session:
        cookie_lifetime: 3600
```

Now it's fine